# Mapping the coefficients of a line to one perpendicular to it

Tags: geometry

Given a line's coefficients $A$, $B$ and $C$  in the form $Ax + By +C =0$.

How can one find a line perpendicular to it passing through a given point, by applying a computation directly on the coefficients and the point which maps them to the coefficients of the perpendicular line in 2-D space.
I am sorry if the question seems I happen to have forgot much of geometry.
Thanks.

$A'$=$B$

$B'$=$-A$

$C'=A'x_1 + B' y_1$

Comment: Coefficients, can you draw a picture? I don't get the question.

Comment: So when you say "coefficients $A,B,C$" are you referring to a line in $Ax+By+C=0$ form?  In that case, you might consider the line $Bx-Ay+Q=0$, where $Q$ is chosen to line up a specific point of intersection...  Note that two lines are perpendicular in Euclidean space when their slopes multiply together to make $-1$...

Comment: Check now it is better explained

Comment: @abiessu Please check if the above mapping is correct.

Comment: The mapping you have chosen will be a perpendicular line, while the value for $C'$ looks arbitrary...  Again, you can pick any point you want to be the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lines are perpendicular their gradients multiply to give -1, for example the normal to a line of gradient 2 is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

You need to find the gradient of $Ax+By+C=0$ and then find the thing that when multiplied with that gradient is -1.

Say the gradient was $m$, and let $n$ be the gradient of the normal, you need $mn=-1$ so $n=\frac{-1}{m}$

Job done.

(I've deliberately not done it for you, you must find the gradient of $Ax+By+C=0$ which isn't hard don't worry!)

Comment: Thanks. $A'$=$B$,

$B'$=$-A$,

$C'=$$A'$ $x_1 + B' y_1$. Should be correct then?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia the A` and B` look good. You need to be more careful for C, see the normal is normal all the way along a line, do you want to make it go through (x1,y1) or meet the other line there or what? But IF THE GRADIENTS ARE -1 WHEN MULTIPLIED THEY ARE PERPENDICULAR. So if the gradients multiply to give -1, you're right!

Comment: Seriously, y=mx+c FTW

Comment: Yeah. Thanks.Cool.